# Remove changes from branch in TFS

Tags: tfs, merge, source-control-explorer

I have a common brach "root" and several child branches. A project with a huge amount of changesets is merged back to the root brach, but a several files have been excluded since the were not nescessary. Those were no seperated changesets.

Now I want to start a new project on that branch, but when I attempt to merge this new project back to the root branch, former excluded files occur again.

So, in between projects for the child branch, it is possible to erase all pending changes compared to root branch?

Answer (score 0):

If these files do not need to be tracked by Version Control, you can create a [tfignore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx) file to exclude them.

If these files need to be tracked by Version Control in the child branch but does not need to be merged into root branch, you can use [tf merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx) command with "**/discard**" specified.

> /discard: Does not perform the merge operation, but updates the merge
>   history to track that the merge occurred. This discards a changeset
>   from being used for a particular merge.